# Selecting a custom cell activates another cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom cell class that has an image, a few text labels(1 truncated), and a button:

```
class CustomTVC: UITableViewCell {

    /* Outlets */
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var concatenatedTitleHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var localDateHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var seeMoreButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on the button, it shows the full description of the truncated text label. However, the problem I have now is when the user clicks on the button for a specific cell, it shows the full description for the cell that the user clicked, and also the full description of another cell.

I know the reason that's happening is because the tableview reuses the cell via dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. How would I go about implementing a function that will make sure that when a user clicks on the button for a specific cell, only that cell's full description is shown?

Code for tableview:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTVC

    if listOfShows.count != 0 {
        // Downloading and displaying picture
        if let downloadPicture: UIImage = helperFunctions.downloadImage(listOfShows[indexPath.row].imageLink) {
            cell.imageHolder.image = downloadPicture
        }
        // Enlarging / dismissing picture
        cell.imageHolder.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let newTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainTVC.imagedTapped(_:)))
        cell.imageHolder.addGestureRecognizer(newTapped)
        // Concatenating channel + series + episode title
        let concatenatedTitle = listOfShows[indexPath.row].channel + " " + listOfShows[indexPath.row].series + " " + listOfShows[indexPath.row].episodeTitle
        // Converting into local date / time
        let universalTime = helperFunctions.localDateAndTimeConverter(listOfShows[indexPath.row].originalAirDate)

        /* Other labels */
        cell.concatenatedTitleHolder.text = concatenatedTitle
        cell.localDateHolder.text = universalTime
        cell.descriptionHolder.text = listOfShows[indexPath.row].description

        cell.seeMoreButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.seeMoreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainTVC.buttonTapped(_:markedArray:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        resetCellSettings(cell)
    }
    return cell
}

func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton, markedArray: [Bool]) {

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTVC

    cell.seeMoreButton.hidden = true
    cell.descriptionHolder.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.descriptionHolder.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.descriptionHolder.sizeToFit()
}

func resetCellSettings(cell: CustomTVC) {
    cell.seeMoreButton.hidden = false
    cell.descriptionHolder.numberOfLines = 1
    cell.descriptionHolder.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
    cell.descriptionHolder.sizeToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put buttonTapped func in CustomTVC class. And set outlet IBAction of seeMoreButton for that func when cell created.